# Why do I get a 'Permission denied'?

Tags: spring-boot, exception, filter, permission-denied

I am running a Spring Boot 2.2.2 application which connects to a Postgres 9.6 DB with already a lot of existing tables. And it's running well.
Now, I want to perform a SELECT against a newly created table from within a filter which extends `org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter`.

The DB table is created and granted with SELECT permission for the used user. Querying the table from within PgAdmin works well but accessing the table via my repository class (called from within the filter class) results in:

```
2020-11-11 19:16:39.077  WARN 4946 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42501
2020-11-11 19:16:39.078 ERROR 4946 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: permission denied for relation my_new_table
2020-11-11 19:16:39.271 ERROR 4946 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
```

The weird thing is that when I submit a SELECT against another table with the same permissions granted like the new table just one LOC ahead... this works like a charm.

When I access the new table much later in the code, e.g. from within a service, it does **NOT** cause the permission denied.

What could be the reason for this behaviour and how can I solve this problem?

---

The filter class:

```
@Service
public class AuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthorizationFilter.class);

private MyPersistenceService myPersistenceService;

public AuthorizationFilter(MyPersistenceService myPersistenceService) {
    this.myPersistenceService = myPersistenceService;
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
...
logger.debug("Authenticating user '{}'", x.getUserId());
                            AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser = AuthenticatedUser.Companion.from(user, grantedAuths, x,
//                                    new ArrayList<Foo>());
                                    myPersistenceService.getFoo(x.getUserId()));
//                            AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser = AuthenticatedUser.Companion.from(user, grantedAuths, x);
                            final C c = myPersistenceService.getC(x.getUserId());
...
```

`myPersistenceService.getFoo()` finally queries my_new_table
`myPersistenceService.getC(x.getUserId());` queries another table in the same schema having exactly equal permissions (ward - UPDATE, INSERT, SELECT, DELETE).

As I already said: It's weird that `getFoo()` fails with **permission denied** but `getC()` works well and it is also weird that when I invoke `getFoo()` later in the code (from a service) I get NO permission denied but a valid `Resultset`.

Comment: Without seeing the actual code, it's nearly impossible to accurately answer your question. You need to show your filter code and how you set up your permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was due to missing permissions for a special user.